# saving a logo illustrator for web with transparent background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, logo

I have a simple b/w logo in illustrator, and want to save this for web use. I am new to web, just savvy in print :(... what is the easiest way to save this file with a transparent background so that it can be placed on various backgrounds?  Thank you.

Comment: don't know why someone downvoted this, i'm a programmer who hates and knows nothing about graphics stuff. this answer was great.

Answer (score 5):

`File > Save For Web...`

Choose PNG24 for the format and click OK.

Comment: Simple question, simple answer. Must've been a long time since you last popped up in 'Low Quality Posts', Scott! :)

Answer (score 0):

Export it as .png file.File->Export, save as type--> .png, untick Use Artboad if you don't want whole art board to be exported.